# ¿Como hacer que el smooth scroll finalice más arriba?

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Estoy utilizando Smooth Scroll y Bootstrap 4 Beta. Lo que quiero hacer es que el smooth scroll finalice un poco más arriba, ya que al tener mi navbar con sticky-top, cuando clickeo y me lleva a donde quiero, queda muy cerca mi navbar y el texto.

Adjunto una imagen de ejemplo por si no se entiende. Esto es lo que me sucede a mí:

[image: Esto me sucede al clickear...]

Esto es lo que busco hacer al clickear. Finalizar el smooth scroll donde comienza el color rojo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste es mi código (también en [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ZeR0ByTe/pen/GMYbXb))

```js
(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define([], factory(root));
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory(root);
  } else {
    root.smoothScroll = factory(root);
  }
})(typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : this.window || this.global, function(root) {

  'use strict';

  //
  // Variables
  //

  var smoothScroll = {}; // Object for public APIs
  var supports = 'querySelector' in document && 'addEventListener' in root; // Feature test
  var settings, anchor, toggle, fixedHeader, headerHeight, eventTimeout, animationInterval;

  // Default settings
  var defaults = {
    selector: '[data-scroll]',
    selectorHeader: null,
    speed: 1000,
    easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
    offset: 20,
    callback: function() {}
  };


  //
  // Methods
  //

  /**
   * Merge two or more objects. Returns a new object.
   * @private
   * @param {Boolean}  deep     If true, do a deep (or recursive) merge [optional]
   * @param {Object}   objects  The objects to merge together
   * @returns {Object}          Merged values of defaults and options
   */
  var extend = function() {

    // Variables
    var extended = {};
    var deep = false;
    var i = 0;
    var length = arguments.length;

    // Check if a deep merge
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[0]) === '[object Boolean]') {
      deep = arguments[0];
      i++;
    }

    // Merge the object into the extended object
    var merge = function(obj) {
      for (var prop in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
          // If deep merge and property is an object, merge properties
          if (deep && Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]') {
            extended[prop] = extend(true, extended[prop], obj[prop]);
          } else {
            extended[prop] = obj[prop];
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // Loop through each object and conduct a merge
    for (; i < length; i++) {
      var obj = arguments[i];
      merge(obj);
    }

    return extended;

  };

  /**
   * Get the height of an element.
   * @private
   * @param  {Node} elem The element to get the height of
   * @return {Number}    The element's height in pixels
   */
  var getHeight = function(elem) {
    return Math.max(elem.scrollHeight, elem.offsetHeight, elem.clientHeight);
  };

  /**
   * Get the closest matching element up the DOM tree.
   * @private
   * @param  {Element} elem     Starting element
   * @param  {String}  selector Selector to match against (class, ID, data attribute, or tag)
   * @return {Boolean|Element}  Returns null if not match found
   */
  var getClosest = function(elem, selector) {

    // Variables
    var firstChar = selector.charAt(0);
    var supports = 'classList' in document.documentElement;
    var attribute, value;

    // If selector is a data attribute, split attribute from value
    if (firstChar === '[') {
      selector = selector.substr(1, selector.length - 2);
      attribute = selector.split('=');

      if (attribute.length > 1) {
        value = true;
        attribute[1] = attribute[1].replace(/"/g, '').replace(/'/g, '');
      }
    }

    // Get closest match
    for (; elem && elem !== document && elem.nodeType === 1; elem = elem.parentNode) {

      // If selector is a class
      if (firstChar === '.') {
        if (supports) {
          if (elem.classList.contains(selector.substr(1))) {
            return elem;
          }
        } else {
          if (new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + selector.substr(1) + '(\\s|$)').test(elem.className)) {
            return elem;
          }
        }
      }

      // If selector is an ID
      if (firstChar === '#') {
        if (elem.id === selector.substr(1)) {
          return elem;
        }
      }

      // If selector is a data attribute
      if (firstChar === '[') {
        if (elem.hasAttribute(attribute[0])) {
          if (value) {
            if (elem.getAttribute(attribute[0]) === attribute[1]) {
              return elem;
            }
          } else {
            return elem;
          }
        }
      }

      // If selector is a tag
      if (elem.tagName.toLowerCase() === selector) {
        return elem;
      }

    }

    return null;

  };

  /**
   * Escape special characters for use with querySelector
   * @private
   * @param {String} id The anchor ID to escape
   * @author Mathias Bynens
   * @link https://github.com/mathiasbynens/CSS.escape
   */
  var escapeCharacters = function(id) {

    // Remove leading hash
    if (id.charAt(0) === '#') {
      id = id.substr(1);
    }

    var string = String(id);
    var length = string.length;
    var index = -1;
    var codeUnit;
    var result = '';
    var firstCodeUnit = string.charCodeAt(0);
    while (++index < length) {
      codeUnit = string.charCodeAt(index);
      // Note: there’s no need to special-case astral symbols, surrogate
      // pairs, or lone surrogates.

      // If the character is NULL (U+0000), then throw an
      // `InvalidCharacterError` exception and terminate these steps.
      if (codeUnit === 0x0000) {
        throw new InvalidCharacterError(
          'Invalid character: the input contains U+0000.'
        );
      }

      if (
        // If the character is in the range [\1-\1F] (U+0001 to U+001F) or is
        // U+007F, […]
        (codeUnit >= 0x0001 && codeUnit <= 0x001F) || codeUnit == 0x007F ||
        // If the character is the first character and is in the range [0-9]
        // (U+0030 to U+0039), […]
        (index === 0 && codeUnit >= 0x0030 && codeUnit <= 0x0039) ||
        // If the character is the second character and is in the range [0-9]
        // (U+0030 to U+0039) and the first character is a `-` (U+002D), […]
        (
          index === 1 &&
          codeUnit >= 0x0030 && codeUnit <= 0x0039 &&
          firstCodeUnit === 0x002D
        )
      ) {
        // http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#escape-a-character-as-code-point
        result += '\\' + codeUnit.toString(16) + ' ';
        continue;
      }

      // If the character is not handled by one of the above rules and is
      // greater than or equal to U+0080, is `-` (U+002D) or `_` (U+005F), or
      // is in one of the ranges [0-9] (U+0030 to U+0039), [A-Z] (U+0041 to
      // U+005A), or [a-z] (U+0061 to U+007A), […]
      if (
        codeUnit >= 0x0080 ||
        codeUnit === 0x002D ||
        codeUnit === 0x005F ||
        codeUnit >= 0x0030 && codeUnit <= 0x0039 ||
        codeUnit >= 0x0041 && codeUnit <= 0x005A ||
        codeUnit >= 0x0061 && codeUnit <= 0x007A
      ) {
        // the character itself
        result += string.charAt(index);
        continue;
      }

      // Otherwise, the escaped character.
      // http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#escape-a-character
      result += '\\' + string.charAt(index);

    }

    return '#' + result;

  };

  /**
   * Calculate the easing pattern
   * @private
   * @link https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294
   * @param {String} type Easing pattern
   * @param {Number} time Time animation should take to complete
   * @returns {Number}
   */
  var easingPattern = function(type, time) {
    var pattern;
    if (type === 'easeInQuad') pattern = time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
    if (type === 'easeOutQuad') pattern = time * (2 - time); // decelerating to zero velocity
    if (type === 'easeInOutQuad') pattern = time < 0.5 ? 2 * time * time : -1 + (4 - 2 * time) * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    if (type === 'easeInCubic') pattern = time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
    if (type === 'easeOutCubic') pattern = (--time) * time * time + 1; // decelerating to zero velocity
    if (type === 'easeInOutCubic') pattern = time < 0.5 ? 4 * time * time * time : (time - 1) * (2 * time - 2) * (2 * time - 2) + 1; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    if (type === 'easeInQuart') pattern = time * time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
    if (type === 'easeOutQuart') pattern = 1 - (--time) * time * time * time; // decelerating to zero velocity
    if (type === 'easeInOutQuart') pattern = time < 0.5 ? 8 * time * time * time * time : 1 - 8 * (--time) * time * time * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    if (type === 'easeInQuint') pattern = time * time * time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
    if (type === 'easeOutQuint') pattern = 1 + (--time) * time * time * time * time; // decelerating to zero velocity
    if (type === 'easeInOutQuint') pattern = time < 0.5 ? 16 * time * time * time * time * time : 1 + 16 * (--time) * time * time * time * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
    return pattern || time; // no easing, no acceleration
  };

  /**
   * Calculate how far to scroll
   * @private
   * @param {Element} anchor The anchor element to scroll to
   * @param {Number} headerHeight Height of a fixed header, if any
   * @param {Number} offset Number of pixels by which to offset scroll
   * @returns {Number}
   */
  var getEndLocation = function(anchor, headerHeight, offset) {
    var location = 0;
    if (anchor.offsetParent) {
      do {
        location += anchor.offsetTop;
        anchor = anchor.offsetParent;
      } while (anchor);
    }
    location = Math.max(location - headerHeight - offset, 0);
    return Math.min(location, getDocumentHeight() - getViewportHeight());
  };

  /**
   * Determine the viewport's height
   * @private
   * @returns {Number}
   */
  var getViewportHeight = function() {
    return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, root.innerHeight || 0);
  };

  /**
   * Determine the document's height
   * @private
   * @returns {Number}
   */
  var getDocumentHeight = function() {
    return Math.max(
      document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
      document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
      document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
  };

  /**
   * Convert data-options attribute into an object of key/value pairs
   * @private
   * @param {String} options Link-specific options as a data attribute string
   * @returns {Object}
   */
  var getDataOptions = function(options) {
    return !options || !(typeof JSON === 'object' && typeof JSON.parse === 'function') ? {} : JSON.parse(options);
  };

  /**
   * Get the height of the fixed header
   * @private
   * @param  {Node}   header The header
   * @return {Number}        The height of the header
   */
  var getHeaderHeight = function(header) {
    return !header ? 0 : (getHeight(header) + header.offsetTop);
  };

  /**
   * Bring the anchored element into focus
   * @private
   */
  var adjustFocus = function(anchor, endLocation, isNum) {

    // Don't run if scrolling to a number on the page
    if (isNum) return;

    // Otherwise, bring anchor element into focus
    anchor.focus();
    if (document.activeElement.id !== anchor.id) {
      anchor.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
      anchor.focus();
      anchor.style.outline = 'none';
    }
    root.scrollTo(0, endLocation);

  };

  /**
   * Start/stop the scrolling animation
   * @public
   * @param {Node|Number} anchor  The element or position to scroll to
   * @param {Element}     toggle  The element that toggled the scroll event
   * @param {Object}      options
   */
  smoothScroll.animateScroll = function(anchor, toggle, options) {

    // Options and overrides
    var overrides = getDataOptions(toggle ? toggle.getAttribute('data-options') : null);
    var animateSettings = extend(settings || defaults, options || {}, overrides); // Merge user options with defaults

    // Selectors and variables
    var isNum = Object.prototype.toString.call(anchor) === '[object Number]' ? true : false;
    var anchorElem = isNum || !anchor.tagName ? null : anchor;
    if (!isNum && !anchorElem) return;
    var startLocation = root.pageYOffset; // Current location on the page
    if (animateSettings.selectorHeader && !fixedHeader) {
      // Get the fixed header if not already set
      fixedHeader = document.querySelector(animateSettings.selectorHeader);
    }
    if (!headerHeight) {
      // Get the height of a fixed header if one exists and not already set
      headerHeight = getHeaderHeight(fixedHeader);
    }
    var endLocation = isNum ? anchor : getEndLocation(anchorElem, headerHeight, parseInt(animateSettings.offset, 10)); // Location to scroll to
    var distance = endLocation - startLocation; // distance to travel
    var documentHeight = getDocumentHeight();
    var timeLapsed = 0;
    var percentage, position;

    /**
     * Stop the scroll animation when it reaches its target (or the bottom/top of page)
     * @private
     * @param {Number} position Current position on the page
     * @param {Number} endLocation Scroll to location
     * @param {Number} animationInterval How much to scroll on this loop
     */
    var stopAnimateScroll = function(position, endLocation, animationInterval) {
      var currentLocation = root.pageYOffset;
      if (position == endLocation || currentLocation == endLocation || ((root.innerHeight + currentLocation) >= documentHeight)) {

        // Clear the animation timer
        clearInterval(animationInterval);

        // Bring the anchored element into focus
        adjustFocus(anchor, endLocation, isNum);

        // Run callback after animation complete
        animateSettings.callback(anchor, toggle);

      }
    };

    /**
     * Loop scrolling animation
     * @private
     */
    var loopAnimateScroll = function() {
      timeLapsed += 16;
      percentage = (timeLapsed / parseInt(animateSettings.speed, 10));
      percentage = (percentage > 1) ? 1 : percentage;
      position = startLocation + (distance * easingPattern(animateSettings.easing, percentage));
      root.scrollTo(0, Math.floor(position));
      stopAnimateScroll(position, endLocation, animationInterval);
    };

    /**
     * Set interval timer
     * @private
     */
    var startAnimateScroll = function() {
      clearInterval(animationInterval);
      animationInterval = setInterval(loopAnimateScroll, 16);
    };

    /**
     * Reset position to fix weird iOS bug
     * @link https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll/issues/45
     */
    if (root.pageYOffset === 0) {
      root.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    // Start scrolling animation
    startAnimateScroll();

  };

  /**
   * Handle has change event
   * @private
   */
  var hashChangeHandler = function(event) {

    // Get hash from URL
    var hash = root.location.hash;

    // Only run if there's an anchor element to scroll to
    if (!anchor) return;

    // Reset the anchor element's ID
    anchor.id = anchor.getAttribute('data-scroll-id');

    // Scroll to the anchored content
    smoothScroll.animateScroll(anchor, toggle);

    // Reset anchor and toggle
    anchor = null;
    toggle = null;

  };

  /**
   * If smooth scroll element clicked, animate scroll
   * @private
   */
  var clickHandler = function(event) {

    // Don't run if right-click or command/control + click
    if (event.button !== 0 || event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) return;

    // Check if a smooth scroll link was clicked
    toggle = getClosest(event.target, settings.selector);
    if (!toggle || toggle.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'a') return;

    // Only run if link is an anchor and points to the current page
    if (toggle.hostname !== root.location.hostname || toggle.pathname !== root.location.pathname || !/#/.test(toggle.href)) return;

    // Get the sanitized hash
    var hash = escapeCharacters(toggle.hash);

    // If the hash is empty, scroll to the top of the page
    if (hash === '#') {

      // Prevent default link behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Set the anchored element
      anchor = document.body;

      // Save or create the ID as a data attribute and remove it (prevents scroll jump)
      var id = anchor.id ? anchor.id : 'smooth-scroll-top';
      anchor.setAttribute('data-scroll-id', id);
      anchor.id = '';

      // If no hash change event will happen, fire manually
      // Otherwise, update the hash
      if (root.location.hash.substring(1) === id) {
        hashChangeHandler();
      } else {
        root.location.hash = id;
      }

      return;

    }

    // Get the anchored element
    anchor = document.querySelector(hash);

    // If anchored element exists, save the ID as a data attribute and remove it (prevents scroll jump)
    if (!anchor) return;
    anchor.setAttribute('data-scroll-id', anchor.id);
    anchor.id = '';

    // If no hash change event will happen, fire manually
    if (toggle.hash === root.location.hash) {
      event.preventDefault();
      hashChangeHandler();
    }

  };

  /**
   * On window scroll and resize, only run events at a rate of 15fps for better performance
   * @private
   * @param  {Function} eventTimeout Timeout function
   * @param  {Object} settings
   */
  var resizeThrottler = function(event) {
    if (!eventTimeout) {
      eventTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        eventTimeout = null; // Reset timeout
        headerHeight = getHeaderHeight(fixedHeader); // Get the height of a fixed header if one exists
      }, 66);
    }
  };

  /**
   * Destroy the current initialization.
   * @public
   */
  smoothScroll.destroy = function() {

    // If plugin isn't already initialized, stop
    if (!settings) return;

    // Remove event listeners
    document.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
    root.removeEventListener('resize', resizeThrottler, false);

    // Reset varaibles
    settings = null;
    anchor = null;
    toggle = null;
    fixedHeader = null;
    headerHeight = null;
    eventTimeout = null;
    animationInterval = null;
  };

  /**
   * Initialize Smooth Scroll
   * @public
   * @param {Object} options User settings
   */
  smoothScroll.init = function(options) {

    // feature test
    if (!supports) return;

    // Destroy any existing initializations
    smoothScroll.destroy();

    // Selectors and variables
    settings = extend(defaults, options || {}); // Merge user options with defaults
    fixedHeader = settings.selectorHeader ? document.querySelector(settings.selectorHeader) : null; // Get the fixed header
    headerHeight = getHeaderHeight(fixedHeader);

    // When a toggle is clicked, run the click handler
    document.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);

    // Listen for hash changes
    root.addEventListener('hashchange', hashChangeHandler, false);

    // If window is resized and there's a fixed header, recalculate its size
    if (fixedHeader) {
      root.addEventListener('resize', resizeThrottler, false);
    }

  };


  //
  // Public APIs
  //

  return smoothScroll;

});
```

```css
.nosotros {
  background-color: #971217;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="img/logoSB.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> Menu de Navegación
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto text-center">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Inicio</a>
      <a data-scroll class="nav-item nav-link" href="#nosotros">Nosotros</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Antorchada</a>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Proyecto +Conciencia
            </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Competencias</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
    </ul>

    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2">Facebook</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Instagram</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
<!-- FIN NAVBAR -->

<!-- NOSOTROS -->
<div class="container-fluid nosotros" id="nosotros">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-5 my-5">
      <h1 class="text-center">NOSOTROS</h1>
      <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias iste explicabo consectetur mollitia aperiam unde dolor molestias quasi, fuga ipsam incidunt fugiat, quia molestiae eveniet. Aspe</p>

      <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias iste explicabo consectetur mollitia aperiam unde dolor molestias quasi, fuga ipsam incidunt fugiat, quia molestiae eveniet. Aspe</p>

      <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias iste explicabo consectetur mollitia aperiam unde dolor molestias quasi, fuga ipsam incidunt fugiat, quia molestiae eveniet. Aspe</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-7 my-5">
      <img src="img/equipo.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- FIN NOSOTROS -->
<!-- +CONCIENCIA -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 conciencia-izquierda ">
      <img src="img/logoSB.png" class="img-fluid p-4" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="col-8 conciencia-derecha">
      <h1 class="text-center p-4">PROYECTO +CONCIENCIA</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Buenas! Coloca algo de tu código para que podamos ayudarte mejor :). De paso, echale un vistazo a [ask].

Comment: Tengo la sospecha de que el problema radica en el elemento que estás definiendo como objetivo en tu barra. Como @GDP señala, es mejor que pongas el código, así se puede ver el problema en la práctica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vos tenes tags que por ahora no tienen css y estan vacios:

```
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Inicio</a>

          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Antorchada</a>
```

Estaria bueno rellenarlos antes de seguir probando con la parte 'nosotros'.

Yo agregue padding-top: 30px; a **.nosotros**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLRejr

Comment: Hola, no complete el resto del CSS porque lo que quería mostrar con un link alcanzaba. Por otro lado, no me refiero a ponerle más padding y "alejar" el texto del div rojo, me refiero a que cuando clickee, el smooth finalice exactamente DONDE EMPIECE el div rojo.